# Programmatically created a new category but cannot be found on admin page

Tags: magento2, category

I would like to write some code to create a new category under root category (as shown below).
The new category has been created at database, but I cannot found it on admin page

```
    /// Get Web Site ID
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    echo $websiteId."/n/r";

    /// Get Store ID
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
    echo $storeId."/n/r";

    /// Get Root Category ID
    $rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
    echo $rootNodeId."/n/r";

    /// Add a new sub category under root category
    $categoryTmp = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $categoryTmp->setName('test');
    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
    $categoryTmp->setUrlKey('test5');
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
    $categoryTmp->setParentId($rootNodeId);
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
    $categoryTmp->save();
```

Comment: My guess problem is reindex so try redindex once

Answer (score 2):

I think should incorrect in setPath. I've amended my code, it work now! thanks.

```
    /// Get Web Site ID
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    echo 'websiteId: '.$websiteId."   ";

    /// Get Store ID
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
    echo 'storeId: '.$storeId."   ";

    /// Get Root Category ID
    $rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
    echo 'rootNodeId: '.$rootNodeId."   ";

    /// Get Root Category
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
    $cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootNodeId);

    /// Add a new sub category under root category
    $categoryTmp = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $categoryTmp->setName('test2');
    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
    $categoryTmp->setUrlKey('test14');
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
    $categoryTmp->setParentId($rootNodeId);
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
    $categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
    $categoryTmp->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

it will help for Programmatically created a new category

```
$parent_cat_id = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;

$parent_category = $this->_objectManager
                      ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
                      ->load($parent_cat_id);
$category_obj = $this->_objectManager
                ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
// Check category exist or not
$cate_data = $category_obj->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name','CATE_NAME')
            ->getFirstItem();

if(!isset($cate_data->getId())) 
{
    $category_obj->setPath($parent_category->getPath())
        ->setParentId($parent_cat_id)
        ->setName('CATE_NAME')
        ->setIsActive(true);
    $category_obj->save();
}
```

Comment: With above code, when flat_category enabled, not creating new categories. When I use $this->_objectManager
                ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository')->save($categoryObj); it is creating new category but not inside default category i.e parentId=2, it is not taking. 
It is creating category inside root only. Can someone resolve?

Comment: Another issue.. With Flat_category enabled , new categories not getting created as flat model is missing validate() function. Anyone has solution?